# C# Naming Conventions of namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming-conventions

At work, they've been quite elaborate with their naming of namespaces (before my time). A typical namespace could be

> CompanyName.SubCompanyName.DepartmentName.ProjectName.UniqueProjectName.ProjectName.FilteredProjectName

Sadly, I'm not joking. The issue is, despite being some clarity as to where the projects live it's just so noisy; I want to shorten it.

I want to use `using` keyword (in regards to declaring which namespaces are to be used) and then equals symbol to use a namespace alias. The issue now turns into ambiguity between a namespace declaration and a class's property. For example

```
Project.Message
```

As it stands, we have no indication if Project is the name of a static class, a namespace or the name of an already initialised object (although the word `this.` would help clarify it).

So, with that background, my question is about naming conventions. For me, it would make sense to use the Hungarian style naming conventions (which I know is now considered fairly outdated these days) so I could do something like

> using nsProject = CompanyName.SubCompanyName.DepartmentName.ProjectName.UniqueProjectName.ProjectName.FilteredProjectName

Please note, I've prefixed it with ns (namespace). Therefore, if the code looks like either of the following, there is at least some clarity:

```
this.Project.Message
nsProject.Message
Project.Message
```

The 3 above examples are fairly clear now: the first has already been declared in the project, the second is the namespace and the third is probably a static method call.

Does any one have any comments about this approach; am I reinventing the wheel (are there already guidelines in place) or does any one have a different opinion on what can be done?

**EDIT**

Another reason for wanting to use Alias's is the current namespaces do not match (or have any significance in some places) to the folder structure. So not only do I want to ensure clarity between what type of object/namespace is being used, but my Alias will also be a guide as to the folder location. I know, this probably reads as hacking etc but (as per comments in this post) it is the first stage of many.

Comment: Rather than finding a workaround for the issue that your namespace structure is unwieldy, why not address the issue head-on? Why do you need aliases at all? (Why not just "normal" using directives?)

Comment: Each project references multiple projects, all with very similar names. The problem is tracking down code. In VS2005 I can't use the Go To Definition (VS doesn't respond) so I'm having to track it manually. There is no documentation so I'm also reading code, line by line to understand it. Therefore, I want something which is easier on the eye but there is clarity into which namespace the object exists within.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have *multiple* problems then - again, I'd urge you to try to tackle the problem at source rather than just addressing the symptoms.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are of course correct; The namespaces used don't even correspond to folder locations (again, hence the desire to alias them); your suggestion is going to be the end goal but this project is vast and I have to conquer it in bite size chunks :)

Comment: @DaveRook Can't you use syntax highlighting for this? By default Visual Studio uses black for properties and namespaces and cyan (not sure about the color name) for classes.

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid Yes, I can, good point, thank you. I had never actually noted the colours. However, based upon your suggestion would I be right in assuming there is no 'standard' of naming alias namespaces?

Comment: Rather than hungarian notation, for your aliases I suggest "using ProjectNamespace = etc", which is more in line with Microsoft naming conventions. But this should be viewed as a short term fix.

Comment: @ShellShock thank you - I have now found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28vs.71%29.aspx  which is namespace guidelines but not updated since .NET 1.1 (maybe because it still applies or they never felt like updating and is outdated - who knows). It's strange, people have had many opinions about type/property naming conventions but not namespace alias. I wonder if this is because it's not too popular.

Comment: Further to my post above, more details for later version of .NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx

Comment: @DaveRook You are right. Microsoft does not explicitly defines any rule for naming namespace aliases. But I believe we should follow the same guidelines for namespace naming. I personally would go with ShellShock's suggestion.

Comment: Those who use namespaces such as 'CompanyName.SubCompanyName.DepartmentName....' usually bitterly regret it each time there is a reorganization.

Comment: @Joe, ha ha, I don't think *they* regret it, the poor bloke (me) who fixes it regrets it :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know of any "Official" guidelines, but whenever I alias a namespace I usually use a contraction of the Company and the Project. This would result in (using your example):

```
this.Project.Message.Send();
CompanyProject.Message.Send();
Project.Message.Send();
```

I prefer postfixing above hungarian btw (subjective I know).

Comment: I agree, the post is going to get subjective answers if there was no guideline - The feeling I get is there is no guideline and it's very much up to the team! Thank you for your time.